# removing specific Key and value from Hstore in postgres

Tags: postgresql, hstore

[image: how to select just red area]i have a data which is in Hstore form so i want to select a specific key and value  from data and then delete them,  as i use this query it is find all rows which this key and value exist on it but i want those rows which is only involve this key and value not all

```
select * from topdog where tags @> 'created_by=>JOSM'
```

thanks

Comment: I have read your question several times but still don't understand what you want to achieve exactly. Can you clarify? And provide your Postgres version and table definition.

Comment: i am using Postgres 9.3
the question is "i want to delete those rows which has just tags("created_by"=>''JOSM'). when i use this query
select * from topdog where tags @> 'created_by=>JOSM'
the result is :


16382115;""name"=>"Vazební věznice Brno", "amenity"=>"prison", "created_by"=>"JOSM"";
18008930;""created_by"=>"JOSM"";
21288991;""created_by"=>"JOSM"";
8166183;""source"=>"uhul:ortofoto", "highway"=>"footway", "created_by"=>"JOSM""; but i want to selected and then delete only rows with tags ""created_by"=>"JOSM"" not all rows

Comment: I hope you don't want to do a OSM mechanical edit to remove those created_by tags; this is discouraged. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:created_by , specially `You should not remove the created_by tag on objects you are not otherwise modifying. If we wanted to remove them in bulk we'd do it some other way.`

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you should use the `=` (equality) operator instead of `@>`(containment).

It will filter only the exact rows and you could use them in a delta statment.

Comment: i have try this and works :                                                                      select * from topdog where tags = '"created_by"=>"JOSM"'                        thanks

Answer (score 0):

use

```
select * from <table> where tags->'created_by' = 'JOSM' and len(akeys("tags"))=1
```

That way you select those that have the created_by tag and only one hstore key.

I don't know if len() is the correct function to use for "array element count" (maybe it's array_length()).

See the hstore doc at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html .

(Disclaimer: I dont have a hstore enabled db to test with)